# Pick a uniform distributed sample in a datatable

Tags: r, data.table, sample

Suppose I have an example dataset looking like this:

```
df = data.table(id = 1:100,group=rep(c('a','b','c','d'),25))
```

I would like to take, let's say, 80 observations from this set in **x** non-overlapping samples. Important feature is that the distribution of each sample must be uniform among each group.

For example:

```
x=20 will give a first sample of
1 a
5 b
15 c
28 d
```

This is a very convenient example, but it must also be applicable to less convenient cases (when x=7 for example).

My first try was using *split*, like this:

```
df_split = split(df, as.numeric(as.factor(df$id)) %% 7)
```

that does what I want, except it does not uniformly pick from each group!

Comment: How do those four observations constitute the "first sample" of "80 observations .. in [20] independent samples"?

Comment: Every 'id' can be present in only 1 sample, so every sample contains unique ids

Comment: If every id can be present in only 1 sample then the results of each sample are dependent on the previous samples, so the samples are not independent.

Comment: Your description seems to be asking for 7 non-overlapping samples which contain a total of 80 observations

Comment: You are right, I erased the word 'independent' from the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, since you are looking for 7 sets of 80 samples, you may want to run this as a loop:

```
dt <- data.table(id = 1:100,group=rep(c('a','b','c','d'),25))

newmat <- data.frame(Index = 1:80)
for(i in 1:7){
  k <- NULL
  for(j in unique(dt$group)){
    dt.sub <- dt[group == j]
    samps <- sample_n(dt.sub, 20, replace = F)
    k <- c(k,samps$id)
  }
  newmat <- cbind(newmat, k)
}

colnames(newmat) <- c("Index", paste0("k",1:7))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I added a line in between that uses a random group-id, so it will not always start picking from the first group. With that added, it does what I want!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this might be what you're looking for:

```
df = data.frame(id = 1:100,group=rep(c('a','b','c','d'),25))

repeat {
  mysample <- sample(df$id, size=4, replace=TRUE)  # takes sample
  test     <- (sum(duplicated(df[mysample, ]$group)) == 0)  # true if no duplicates

  if (test == 1)
    break
}

mysample
df[mysample, ]  # retrieves data
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Not exactly what I'm looking for; I need the total set (so all non-overlapping samples) and it needs to find out itself how big the samples must be (based on x; the number of samples)